# RavenDB - How to get the matched terms/tokens for fuzzy search or substring search?

Tags: ravendb

I'm busy with a google like implementation using jquery's autocomplete. I have a few questions:

1)At the moment my basic Query looks like this using a SimpleAnalyzer to get results. SearchQuery is a combination of a few fields.

```
                var results = session.Query<Project, Project_QueryIndex>()

                .Search(x => x.SearchQuery, "overfl*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard)
                .Search(x => x.SearchQuery, "overflew~0.6", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery)
```

This will return documents with "overflow" in the document name. My idea was to use the matched term(s) to populate the autocomplete list as you type. RavenDb's suggestions doesn't work as I want it to work and obviously will not work when using wildcard searches. Is there a way to get the matched term(s)/tokens for results? Or another way to implement this?

2) If I can solve 1, then this isn't a problem. I wanted to use the highlighting of Ravendb to try and solve this. But I see Ravendb's highlighter doesn't highlight the results when using fuzzy search or substring searches. Can the highlighter be implemented in such a way?

3) Can you use Lucene.net within Ravendb, like is it possible to use QueryParsers from Lucene.net, like MultiFieldQueryParser etc. Just want to know how if possible?

Thanx. I have scoured the internet for answers, but if I missed something, please post any relevant info to I might have missed to implement a google like autocomplete/search site.